# как правильно обновить запись в базе данных используя spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

пытаюсь обновить запись но получаю ошибки, в попытке предотвратить их появление решил что делаю что-то не правильное.
Подскажите, что не правильно делаю?

есть класс User:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "user")
    public class User {
        @Id
        @Column(name = "id")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Integer id;

        @Column(name="name")
        private String name;

        @Column(name="name")
        private String login;

       //getters and setters
    }
```

UserDao:

```
@Repository
public class UserDao{
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
    public void updateUser(User user) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.update(user);
    }
    public User getForId(Integer id) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    User user = (User) session.load(User.class, new Integer(id));
    return user;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void update(User user) {
    service.updateUser(user);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/updateUser/{id}")
public String updateUser(@PathVariable("id")int id, Model model) {
    User user = service.getForId(id);
    model.addAttribute("user",user);
    return "update";
}
```

update.jsp:

```
<form:form action="/update" method="post" commandName="user">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="name">name
                    </form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="login">name
                    </form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="login" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Ok" onclick="/" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
```

это кнопка на созданном объекте которая вызывает /updateUser

```
   <table>
        <c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
             <tr>
                <td><a href="delete/${user.id}">Удалить</a></td>
                <td><a href="updateUser/${user.id}">Изменить</a>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

ошибка:

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: The given object has a null identifier: com.model.User
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.getUpdateId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultUpdateEventListener.getUpdateId(DefaultUpdateEventListener.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultUpdateEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireUpdate(SessionImpl.java:739)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.update(SessionImpl.java:731)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.update(SessionImpl.java:726)
    at com.dao.UserDAO.updateUser(UserDao.java:47)
    at com.service.UserService.updateUser(UserService.java:30)
    at com.service.UserService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$12de773.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at com.service.UserService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e21bb612.updateUser(<generated>)
    at com.controller.UserController.update(UserController.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Comment: Полный текст ошибки добавьте к вопросу.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Сделал

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev вот вновь ошибка - org.hibernate.persistentobjectexception detached entity passed to persist spring

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, в форме отсутствует поле для идентификатора, поэтому он не установлен у аргумента `user`. Кроме того атрибут `commandName` давно устарел, сейчас вместо него используется `modelAttribute`. Измените форму так:

```
<form:form action="/update" method="post" modelAttribute="user">
    <form:hidden path="id" />
    ...
</form:form>
```

Во-вторых, пометьте параметр метода [аннотацией](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String update(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
    service.updateUser(user);
    return "redirect:/some-success-url";
}
```

Наконец, в `user` вы получите экземпляр класса `User`, содержащий данные, но не связанный с сессией Hibernate, находящийся [в состоянии detached](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc). Самый простой способ решить эту проблему - заменить в методе `UserDAO.updateUser()` вызов `session.update(user)` на `session.saveOrUpdate(user)`.

Comment: сделал проверку на null, подправил с учетом Ваших рекомендаций, но ошибка по прежнему та же.

Comment: )))))Да, это именно то.Спасибо большущее!

Comment: это команда теперь добавляет ещё один обьект в базу, но не изменяет.

Comment: этот объект существует, я просто не вставил здесь методы добавление юзера

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за помощь, проблему решил.

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил, в методе dao изменил метод и всё стало работать хорошо.

```
public void updateUser(User user) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    User user1 = (User)session.load(User.class, user.getId());
    user1.setName(user.getName());
    user1.setLogin(user.setLogin());
    session.update(user1);
}
```

Comment: У вас теперь делается дополнительный запрос.